# Azure Function Service Bus - Managed Identity - Service Bus account connection string

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-identity

I've followed the azure guides on setting up a managed identity for Service Bus. I'm running into the following error:

```
Service Bus account connection string 'ServiceBusConnection' does not exist.
```

I do have the `"connection"` in the function.json listed as "`ServiceBusConnection`"

In the live metrics I get this error when sending from the queue.

```
Service Bus account connection string 'ServiceBus' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
```

I do have in my settings for the function app and locally the following configuration:

```
"ServiceBusConnection_fullyQualifiedNamespace":"<xxxxx>.servicebus.windows.net"
```

I've also defined `AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName`

I seem to be very stuck, followed the azure guides, can't find anything I'm doing wrong.

Comment: so once deployed do you have a `ServiceBusConnection_fullyQualifiedNamespace` app setting ? `local.settings.json` is not published by default.

Comment: @Thomas yes. I have it listed in the configuration of the function app.

Comment: Oh I think there is a typo you have only one _ but you should have two: `ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace`

Comment: you can also define it like that: `ServiceBusConnection:fullyQualifiedNamespace`

Comment: @Thomas good eye, in my settings.json I had one underscore, but in the deployment i have two. So i'm still stumped there

Comment: so it s working locally ?

Comment: Also do you have the managed identity set up properly ?

Comment: @Thomas there might be some more configurations i didn't set up locally. I'm more focused on the deployment truthfully. Managed identity I have set up working properly with other aspects, I think I set it up properly here. However it's possible I missed something. I gave the managed identity permissions over the storage.

Comment: I'd also add that i'm getting this error in the live metrics: The listener for function 'Functions.TimerTrigger' was unable to start AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Comment: you would need to set up permission to servicebus as well tho

Comment: I did set up service bus permissions with the recommended permissions. I'm also not sure that explain this error: Service Bus account connection string 'ServiceBus' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.

Comment: so still the same error ....

Comment: Unfortunately i've made no progress on this.

Comment: which azure function runtime are you using? v4 ? could you confirm it is working fine locally ?

Comment: v4. I can confirm it's working locally, however I have Function TimerTrigger disabled. But the serviceBusQueueTrigger is working as expected

Answer (score 3):

Wow, this took me too long to figure out, although I'm not sure why it behaves this way.

Looks like the error message I was getting was very telling.

I switched `"ServiceBusConnection_fullyQualifiedNamespace"` to `"ServiceBus_fullyQualifiedNamespace"` because it said `Service Bus account connection string 'ServiceBus' does not exist.`

This did work. I'm still unclear as to why I can't name the connection prefix as I please.

[Connection string details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-javascript#connection-string)

Comment: Good to see that you sort it out :-)